# How to convert a RISC-V QEMU command line invocation into a virt-manager VM?

Tags: qemu, virt-manager

I have successfully set up a QEMU RISC-V VM from the instructions [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-a-risc-v-virtual-machine-using-a-server-install-image-and-qemu/27636).

My final working CLI invocation is:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -m 4G -smp cpus=2 -nographic \
    -bios /usr/lib/riscv64-linux-gnu/opensbi/generic/fw_jump.bin \
    -kernel /usr/lib/u-boot/qemu-riscv64_smode/u-boot.bin \
    -netdev user,id=net0 \
    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
    -drive file=qemu_disk.bin,format=raw,if=virtio \
    -device virtio-rng-pci \
    -vga virtio \
    -no-reboot
```

Now I want to take the existing qemu_disk.bin image, and run it via virt-manager.

To do this, I tried creating a new VM, specifying the architecture as riscv64

[image]

(which then changes the UI to this:
[image]

And then I select the disk image manually as follows:
[image]

and I indicate that it's running Ubuntu 22.04
[image]

In the end, after the VM has been created, it will not boot. I suspect this is because of the lack of the custom -bios and -kernel arguments.

I tried using virsh to add a `<bios>/usr/lib/riscv64-linux-gnu/opensbi/generic/fw_jump.bin</bios>` tag under `<domain>`, and a `<kernel>/usr/lib/u-boot/qemu-riscv64_smode/u-boot.bin</kernel>` tag under `<os>`. However it still didn't boot.

What is the correct way to import this existing working qemu invocation into virt-manager?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps that you did and then manually edited the XML of the boot options in virt-manager. Here's my `<domain><os>` section:

```
  <os>
    <type arch="riscv64" machine="virt">hvm</type>
    <loader type="rom">/var/lib/libvirt/images/qemu-riscv64_smode/opensbi.bin</loader>
    <kernel>/var/lib/libvirt/images/qemu-riscv64_smode/u-boot.bin</kernel>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
```

You still have to adjust the paths to your opensbi/u-boot binaries.